# Export specific Firestore subcollection

Tags: export, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to export/import a specific sub-collection in Firestore using the beta version of the firestore export tool.

For example, if I have a setup of

- companies
- companies/{company}/users
- teams
- teams/{team}/users

I want to just get the companies collection and all of its subcollections, I was looking to do:

```
gcloud beta firestore export gs://my-bucket-name/fs_backups/companies --collection-ids='companies','users'
```

And I would get `companies`, `companies/{company}/users` and `teams/{company}/users`.

I was trying all of these combos:

```
... -collection-ids='companies/{id}/users'
... -collection-ids='companies/./users'
... -collection-ids='companies/.*/users'
... -collection-ids='companies/*/users'
... -collection-ids='companies/**/users'
... -collection-ids='companies/__name__/users'
```

and some other ones as well, but was getting empty (but not failing) results.

Is there a notation for the collection ids to specify the subcollection that I am looking to export?

Answer (score 11):

I ran into the same problem. The issue is that at least two subcollections, in your example, have the name `users`. The export functionality, when selecting specific collections/subcollections, "flattens" the data (i.e. subcollections will be exported into its own folder, as opposed to a subfolder within the parent collection). This makes subcollections with the same name ambiguous. The fix is to uniquely name subcollections and collections (this will also be helpful if you plan to later import it into BigQuery).

Comment: This sucks. As it means that I have to "recreate" collections which already have thousands of documents in them. And additionally it would mess up my cloud functions triggers that work like `.document('users/{userId}/messages/{messageId}')`. Do you know if I can combine wildcards with names? so for example `.document('users/{userId}/{userId}_messages/{messageId}')`

Comment: Sucks indeed. This was posted beginning of 2019, and we are mid-way into 2020. Any update if this is still true?

Comment: I totally agree with the previous comments. Firestore deserves a more granular way to specify which collection (i.e. parent or sub-collections) to export and import. It's now 2021. Can I make a feature request to make this happen?